# Declaring variable outside of class

Tags: typescript

I was looking at setting up Apollo in Angular and I saw that they create some variables outside of classes.
Why do they do this? Is there any advantage doing this rather than creating a readonly variable?

Where I saw this: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/queries.html#basics

```
// imports....

const CurrentUserForProfile = gql`
   query CurrentUserForProfile {
       currentUser {
          login
          avatar_url
       }
    }
`;

@Component({ ... })
class ProfileComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    loading: boolean;
```

Comment: It's largely an organizational preference. The module level `const` is very much like a `static readonly` class property. One might argue the module level `const` is a bit more conventional in JavaScript, while `static readonly` feels a bit more traditional OOP, but they are pretty much equivalents.